# Pandas DataFrame conditions across rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this sample data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [1987, 1987, 1988, 1988, 1989, 1989], 
    'product':['p1', 'p2', 'p1', 'p2', 'p1', 'p2'], 
    'price': [25, 30, 28, 29, 27, 30],
})
```

What is the best method to extract rows where product price in a particular year is higher (or lower) than value in the previous year? E.g., p1's price is higher in 1988 compared to 1987.
My real data spreads over many years and some new products enter the market in some years while a few others may get discontinued.

Comment: kindly add your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), as follows:

Firstly, sort your dataset by `year`, just in case some data are not already sorted in year order.  Of course, you can skip this step if your data is already sorted in this order:

```
df1 = df.sort_values('year')
```

Then, use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to locate the rows where when grouped by `product` the current price is higher than the last price by  [`.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) > 0:

```
df1.loc[df1.groupby('product')['price'].diff() > 0]
```

[`.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) calculates the difference of a Series element compared with another element in the Series (default is element in previous row).  Hence, when [`.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) > 0, current year price is higher than previous year price.

You can change the comparison to `< 0` when you want to extract the case when current year price is lower than last year price.

**Result:**

```
   year product  price
2  1988      p1     28
5  1989      p2     30
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) in combination with [`pandas.DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) like this:

```
>>> df = df.sort_values(by=['product', 'year'])
>>> df[df.price > df.groupby('product').price.shift()]
   year product  price
2  1988      p1     28
5  1989      p2     30
```

Basically, you can group your data by product and find out the previous value by `shift()` method. To ensure you are looking at the previous year value, I would suggest to sort values in you data frame first.